# Hover effect moving text

Tags: html, css, hover, navbar

For some reason the hover effects on my website seem to move the text when they're highlighted.

Here are the examples:

http://gyazo.com/165d4f93909770c14387e574420a3db8

I was wondering if anyone could help me make it so the text remains still when highlighted with the hover effect.

Here is the CSS for the Nav bar:

```
    /*TOP NAV BAR SECTION*/
#nav_bar {
    background-color: #a22b2f;
    padding:1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px;
    height:45px;
    }         
#nav_bar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav_bar ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
}
#nav_bar ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
#nav_bar>ul>li>a:hover {
    background:#8c1b1f;
    padding-bottom:13px;
    padding-top:17px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;   
}
#nav_bar>ul>li>ul>li>a:hover {
    background:#c9c9c9;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;

}
#nav_bar ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:5px;
    }#nav_bar ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;`enter code here`
}
#nav_bar ul li:hover ul li a {
    color: black;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin-left:-15px;
```

And the HTML for the Nav bar:

```
<!--TOP NAV BAR SECTION-->
            <div id="nav_bar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="status.html">STATUS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="info.html">INFO</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">GAMEMODES</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="survival.html">SURVIVAL</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><br><a href="pure-pvp.html">PURE-PVP</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><br><a href="gamesworld.html">GAMESWORLD</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="rules.html">RULES</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="vote.html">VOTE</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: You're adding padding on hover. Remove that or add the padding to the unhovered text as well.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if it's me but I see other websites with hover padding and there text doesn't move. This website for example:https://woodycraft.net/

Comment: That website does not change the padding on the menu when you hover. It just changes the color.

Comment: Is my website working the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding padding when you hover, this will make the element larger if the interior elements are still the same size. Move the padding to the unhovered element like

```
#nav_bar ul li a {
    color: white;
    padding-bottom:13px;
    padding-top:17px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;   
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y803q0nr/

Comment: Oh thanks! btw is it normal that it spreads the text out more?

Comment: @Grant, that's the padding. Padding is the distance between the content inside of the element and the edge of the box. Read about the box model here, http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Comment: ok thanks, also how would I stop the text moving on the drop down menu? I'm not sure